# python variable assignment index Error: list index out of range with pulp

Tags: python-3.x, list, variables, indexing, pulp

Hi I don't understand how this error is generated.  I have the same amount of constraints on the left side and same amount of element in the list on the right side.  maybe I am missing a small sign or my logic is wrong.  please help me to understand.

```
Machines = ["A", "B",]
Days= ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", 
        "Saturday", "Sunday"]

desire_num={"A":5, "B":2,}

week1={"Monday":1, "Tuesday":1, "Wednesday":1, "Thursday":1,   
       "Friday":1, "Saturday":1, "Sunday":1}

status_list=['1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', 
            '1', '0', '0']



avail = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("var", ((machine, day) for machine in 
           Machines for day in Days), cat="Binary")

##---problem is here.  I have 14 variables on the left and 14 elements in the list on the right.  The error says list index out of range.
status_list_iterator = 0
    for machine, day in avail:
        self.prob += avail[machine, day] ==   
        status_list[status_list_iterator]
        status_list_iterator+=1
```

thanks again for some clarification.

Answer (score 1):

The `rhs` of a constraint should contain at least a numeric value (a boolean one is fine too). You are setting constraint of the form:

```
self.prob += avail[machine, day] == '1' 
#or
self.prob += avail[machine, day] == '0'
```

You can either change the elements in status_list to be `numeric values` or do something like as follows:

```
for (machine, day), status in zip(avail, status_list):
    prob += avail[(machine, day)] == int(status), "c_{}_{}".format(machine, day)
```